# Предупреждение: Load FXML document with JavaFX API of version

Tags: javafx, fxml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как обновить JavaFX в рабочем проекте e(fx)clipse? Вон там снизу написано WARNING, если что.. Да, я тупенький, не судите строго. И ещё я не знаю, зачем обязательно 30 символов надо писать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Warning` из-за того, что в `fxml` у рутового элемента прописано что-то такое:

```
<Pane ... xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" ...>
```

что означает, что вы создали документ из под `JDK11`, а запускаете под `JDK8`, и java-машина не уверена, что все правильно распарсит и знает о существовании всех используемых элементов.

А 30 символов нужно писать, чтобы код с вопросом и возникающие ошибки и предупреждения скидывали текстом, а не картинкой, ведь текст можно скопировать и он проще воспринимается визуально.